# Extract host name/domain name from URL string

Tags: java, string, url

I have a URL like `http://hostname:port_no/control/login.jsp`.

I have the above url stored in some String.Now, I need to extract `hostname` from the String.

I am doing like this in my Java code

```
String domain = url.substring(url.indexOf('/') + 2, url.lastIndexOf(':'));
```

I want to know if there is any better way to do the same.

Comment: You could try using: [URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) class for parsing.

Comment: I request you to change subject of question to 'Get extract host name/domain name from url string' please do needfull

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the [`java.net.URI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html)-class to extract the hostname from the string.

Here below is a method from which you can extract your hostname from a string.

```
public String getHostName(String url) {
    URI uri = new URI(url);
    String hostname = uri.getHost();
    // to provide faultproof result, check if not null then return only hostname, without www.
    if (hostname != null) {
        return hostname.startsWith("www.") ? hostname.substring(4) : hostname;
    }
    return hostname;
}
```

This above gives you the hostname, and is faultproof if your hostname does start with either `hostname.com/...` or `www.hostname.com/...`, which will return with 'hostname'.

If the given `url` is invalid (undefined hostname), it returns with null.

Comment: +1, Using `URI` is _safer_ (and better) than using `URL` alone.

Answer (score 8):

```
java.net.URL aURL;
try {
    aURL = new java.net.URL("http://example.com:80/docs/");
    System.out.println("host = " + aURL.getHost()); //example.com
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: you can use this or you can use regular expressions. Look for class `Pattern` and `Matcher`.

Answer (score 7):

```
java.net.URL u = new URL("http://hostname:port_no/control/login.jsp");
System.err.println(u.getHost());
```

Comment: System.out.println()??

Comment: @MaciejCygan I believe it's an _awesome_ [troll](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-trolling/info).

Comment: @ambigram_maker indeed it is ;)

Comment: `all good but why Sys.err ??` A: It is a valid use case for the method getHost(). It is an **example**.

Comment: Best answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using Regular expression and group:

```
    String pattern = "(\\w*://)([\\w-_.]+)([:\\w\\W]*)";
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m = r.matcher(a);
    if (m.find())
    {
        System.out.println(m.group(0));
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
        System.out.println(m.group(2));
        System.out.println(m.group(3));
    }
```

group(2) is the hostname.

Answer (score 0):

If you want string work, then try the following code sample,

```
String URL= "http://hostname:port_no/control/login.jsp";
String s_URL[] = ULR.split("//");
String s1 = s_URL[1];
String s2[] = s1.split(":");
String hostname = s2[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java:

```
String hostname = url.split("://")[1].split(":")[0];
String portnumber = url.split("://")[1].split(":")[1].split("/")[0];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

@KarelG's answer is the best answer, though I had specific issues with certain non-standard domains.  The example issue is self contained below.

For certain "real world" input values, I had to add a check to the URI scheme to avoid mis-parsing of some addresses.  This is the changed code.

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.*;

public class Domain {
    public static String getDomainName(String url) {
        try {
            URI uri = new URI(url);
            String domain = uri.getHost();
            System.out.println("domain: " + domain);
            if (uri.getScheme() != null) {
                return domain.startsWith("www.") ? domain.substring(4) : domain;
            } else {
                return uri.getSchemeSpecificPart();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Below is the test case and value that was failing.

Domain.java
javac Domain.java
java Domain

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Domain {

    public static String longname = "https://www.3dprintingmedia.network/longform/page.html";
    public static String name = "www.3dprintingmedia.network";

    public static void getDomain(String url) {
        try {
                        URI uri = new URI(url);
                        String domain = uri.getHost();
            System.out.println("protocol: " + uri.getScheme());
            System.out.println("path: " + uri.getPath());
                        System.out.println("name: " + name);
                        System.out.println("domain: " + domain);
                        System.out.println(domain.startsWith("www.") ? domain.substring(4) : domain);
        } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
        }
   }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println("Parsing domain: " + name); 
       getDomain(longname);
       getDomain(name);
       System.exit(0);
    }
}
```