# Get relevant part of domain name in Java

Tags: java

If we have an url e.g `www.google.de` how can I get ONLY the "google"

In Java `new URL (url).getHost();` does work but it gives me `google.de`
and this is not what I want to have.

Thank you

EDIT: If we have something like `www.google.co.uk` then I also want to have only "google" as result.

I dont want "google.de" or "www.google" I ONLY want "google"

Comment: That's not called a hostname.

Comment: What do you want to get from `www.google.co.uk`?

Comment: @SLaks when we have  `www,google.co.uk` I also want only "google"

Comment: you can use [StringTokenizer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get domain name from given url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607903/get-domain-name-from-given-url)

Comment: No, it is not a duplicate.  In this thread I want to have only "google", in your posted link, one wants "google.de" , it is a different problem here.

Comment: You're going to have to create your own rules. On what basis are you choosing "google" from "www.google.co.uk"? Second element? First element but ignoring "www" as a special case? What other special cases do you want to ignore? It's your requirement - you have to define it.

Comment: So update the question, saying different from that question

Comment: What do you want to get from `photos.google.co.uk` vs. `photos.google.de`? You need to precisely define your requirements, at which point you can then translate that into code.

Comment: The part you want to ignore, i.e. the www actually _is_ the hostname.

Comment: Also "www.google.co.uk" is not a URL. It's a domain name. URLs start with a scheme.

Comment: Stepping back, I think this is an XY problem. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem -- why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Splitting on a period and selecting the first or second element (whichever is not "www") would work:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.host.ext.ext");
String host = url.getHost(); // host = "www.host.ext.ext"
String splitHost = host.split("\\.") // splitHost = { "www", "host", "ext", "ext" }

host = splitHost[0].equals("www") ? splitHost[1] : splitHost[0]; // host = "host"
```

If there is anything more than `http://www.` before it, and the extension is potentially more than two "extensions" (`.co.uk` for instance), then there is no easy way to get just the part you want. As far as I know, you would have to try iterating over a list of extensions and return the part immediately before the longest matching extension.

Comment: This [works](https://glot.io/snippets/ermp6i0mvo) but I agree with the comment above that this is likely an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/160897) and there is missing information why "google" is more useful than "google.com".

Comment: Yeah, I think I agree as well now.

Comment: While it is possible this is an XY, I think it could also be exactly what they're asking. Perhaps they actually want to display the important part, ignoring the extension? Although that might be problem X now that I think about it; "how do I display a website's display name/title?"

Comment: Also, could anyone explain the downvote? The answer does exactly what the asker asked for, and explains the one possible pitfall. Help us out here.

Answer (score 0):

The most basic solution would be using

```
 System.out.println(url.split("\\.")[1]);
```

Or you could try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/23079402/2555419

```
public String getHostName(String url) {
    URI uri = new URI(url);
    String hostname = uri.getHost();
    // to provide faultproof result, check if not null then return only hostname, without www.
    if (hostname != null) {
        return hostname.startsWith("www.") ? hostname.substring(4) : hostname;
    }
    return hostname;
}
```

Comment: He needs to specify his question, but he probably actually wants a ccTLD list.

Comment: Yeah probably, I just gave him the most basic solution so he can have somewhere to start from if he wants to use String manipulation.