# Java regex to extract host name and domain name from a URL

Tags: java, regex

I have already viewed and tried multiple other threads and doesn't work for me. **I need the regex solution** for it to work and no java code that does it without regex.

Some of the threads which I have already checked:
[Get domain name from given url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607903/get-domain-name-from-given-url), [Extract host name/domain name from URL string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23079197/extract-host-name-domain-name-from-url-string), and  [Java regex to extract domain name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25884649/java-regex-to-extract-domain-name)
None work for me, either the regex doesn't work or the solution is a java code without regex.

What I am trying to do?

```
Case 1:
Input: https://api.twitter.com/blog/category/2?user=42&status=enabled
Output: api.twitter.com

Input: abc.xyz.com/blog/category/2?user=42&status=enabled
Output: abc.xyz.com

Case 2:
Input: https://abc.xyz.com/blog/category/2?user=42&status=enabled
Output: xyz.com

Input: abc.xyz.com/blog/category/2?user=42&status=enabled
Output: xyz.com
```

I need 2 regexes to solve each case mentioned above. If it can be done in one, even that works.

I tried the below regex from the first post:

```
^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?
```

This one works when there is `https://` or any scheme but fails when there is no scheme in the URL.

So far I am solving the first case using a 2 step solution.

```
Step 1: Replace scheme
(.*://)(.*) -> $2
remove anything before and including string "://"

Step 2: Extract host name
([^/]*)(.*) -> $1
The first group extracts everything that is before the first "/". Basically extracting everything that isn't slash till I see the first one.
```

Comment: Why is the ```abc``` not part of the output in case 2 and how would a regex know when to use which?

Comment: Do you understand the regexp you quoted? (As in, enough to debug and maintain it)

Comment: For case 2,  I can use 2 step solution. If case 1 works for me. First, extract the hostname then the domain name from it.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I am looking for solution. I can assure you I won't put something in production If I don't understand it. In fact, I am trying to understand the regex to make it work for my use case. I am certainly not a regex expert, at least not this complex one :D

Comment: I need these regexes to be used in search engines(elastic search). I would have preferred a easily understandable java code, but that is something I can't put in elastic search schema mapping.

Comment: I think you should look for another solution because regexps are not magic.  Have you had a closer look on the URL class?

Comment: Do you want to match what you call the "output"  as group 1 of the match? Or do you want to match any url with `".xyz.com/"` in it?

Comment: not necessarily group one. If I can extract that in any group that works. For instance, in the regex I quoted, the pattern I am looking for is in group 4.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Yes, I understand it is not magic. I know the URL class and the solution to it. As I said I need this for my ES analyzers. Changing at other places with a URL or a piece of java code is not possible or an option. If it is not possible I have another "inefficient" solution using ES tokenizers, that will still tokenize and keep the domain as split tokens.

Comment: @Bohemian not specifically `.xyz.com` it can be any domain name.

Comment: @BikasKatwal: Why does output #2 show `abc.xyz.com` but output #3 and #4 show only `xyz.com`?

Comment: I need both the strings(domain name and host name).

Comment: I have edited my question with my 2 step solution for the first case. It would be great if that can be done in a single step. But I think that isn't possible? As I do not know if the scheme will be there or not?

Comment: ok [check this](https://regex101.com/r/XNO1NB/1)

Comment: @anubhava thanks! that works :) Could you add this as the answer? and I will use this `.*` instead of `https`. As the scheme can be anything, forgot to mention it in question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this regex with optional matches and capture groups:

```sh
^(?:\w+://)?((?:[^./?#]+\.)?([^/?#]+))
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XNO1NB/3)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?:\w+://)?`: Optionally match scheme names followed by `://`
- `(`: Start capture group #1

  - `(?:[^./?#]+\.)?`: Optionally match first part of domain name using a non-capture group
  - `([^/?#]+)`: Match 1+ of any character that is not `/`, `?`, `#` in capture group #2
- `)`: End capture group #1